# Multiple returns in a reduce function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, reduce

i want to concat several dataframes.

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [1,2,3], "c": [9,8,7]})
df_t2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [np.nan,0,3], "d": [9,8,7]})
...
```

before doing so i have to call another function which takes a dataframe and returns a dataframe and a list

e.g.:

```
def do(a):
  a = sth(a)
  return a, a.columns.tolist()
```

i want to apply the concat function to each dataframe and extend the list of returned columns for each dataframe

```
reduce(lambda y, y2: pd.concat([y,y2]), map(lambda x: do(x), [df_t,df_t2,...]))
```

However, i get an error as it tried to concat my lists in the second iteration. Is this even possible to be solved within a reduce? Is there another memory-friendly approach to solve this?

Goal is to have a concated and processed dataframe and a list of all columns.

Comment: is there a particular reason to structure the code like this? it's not easily readable and is not exactly Pythonic

Comment: i am open to any suggestions :) i just wanted to avoid using a loop and appending

Comment: what is the expected output, please elaborate a bit more

Comment: a large (concated) dataframe build from a list of dataframes (processed/exploded columns ... --> by a different function) and a list of columns contained in each seperate dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Offload the column processing to a shared variable that is updated prior to your higher order functions running.

```
from threading import Lock

class Store:
    data = []
    lock = Lock()


def do(df):
    df = sth(df)
    lock = Store.lock
    lock.acquire()
    Store.data.append(df.columns.tolist())
    lock.release()
    return df

reduce(lambda y, y2: pd.concat([y,y2]), map(lambda x: do(x), [df_t,df_t2]))

   a    b    c    d
0  0  1.0  9.0  NaN
1  1  2.0  8.0  NaN
2  2  3.0  7.0  NaN
0  0  NaN  NaN  9.0
1  1  0.0  NaN  8.0
2  2  3.0  NaN  7.0

print(Store.data)
>> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
```

Comment: is this the only possibility you can think of atm? i also had this in mind but the problem is that the function is part of a bigger implementation being potentially called from multiple points (even maybe in parallel). This is why i wanted to avoid having an "instance attribute" which is updated

Comment: we can add a sync primitive to allow access by one actor at a time, I tried to keep the answer as close to the original approach as possible

Comment: updated it to include the pattern I mention